# SQL Random N rows for each distinct value in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, random

I have the following table:

```
Name    Field
A        1
B        1
C        1
D        1
E        1
F        1
G        1
H        2
I        2
J        2
K        3
L        3
M        3
N        3
O        3
P        3
Q        3
R        3
S        3
T        3
```

I need a SQL query which will generate me a set with 5 random rows for each distinct value on column Field.

For example, results expected:

```
Name    Field
A         1
B         1
D         1
E         1
G         1
J         2
I         2
H         2
M         3
Q         3
T         3
S         3
P         3
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Or should i split that table into more tables and generate random for each table then union them?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with a `CTE` using a `ROW_NUMBER()` whilst `PARTITION`ing on the `Field`:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  Name, Field,
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By Field Order By NewId()) RN
    From    YourTable
)
Select  Name, Field
From    Cte
Where   RN <= 5
```

[<kbd>**SQL Fiddle**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/10082/1/0)

Comment: But i need the rows to be random. this doesn't make my rows random. EDIT: sorry, you are right. thanks for help

Comment: @bucurvlad The `ORDER BY NewId()` portion in the `OVER` clause will order them randomly within each distinct field number.  This will then select the first five in the random order.

Comment: @bucurvlad Added SQL Fiddle demo

Answer (score 5):

You can readily do this with `row_number()`:

```
select name, field
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by field order by newid()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

An enhancement to `Gordon Linoff's code`, This code really helped me if you need criteria in your query.

```
select *
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by region order by newid()) as seqnum
      from MyTable t
      WHERE t.program = 'ACME'
     ) t
where seqnum <= 1500;
```